# Is there a way to throttle readStream into N lines per X timeframe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've tried various ways including line-by-line package but for some reason readStream always faster, less buggy and I assume it's because libuv uses threads for streams.

So, I'm wondering how can I throttle readStream into 10000 lines per 1 min?

Right now, I'm using hacky solutions such as splitting csv into 5 separate files and run script on each, but this doesn't looks elegant to me.

I believe it's theoretically possible to do this directly with streams but I don't know how maybe it involves pause and resume calls on stream.